# how to pass selected Image from gallary to Bitmap

Tags: android

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.apples); 

 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Log.i("Image select","Selected Image");
                    selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                    selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                    System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
               //     Toast.makeText(SocialTwitter.this, "Message not posted on " + selectedImagePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
```

in place of resourse i want to pass selectedImageUri how can i do plz help me 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri targetUri = data.getData();
            String selectedImagePath = getPath(targetUri);
            Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);


BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap2);
yourImageView.setImageDrawable(bd);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to get bitmap

```
   if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE)
   {
      Uri imageUri = data.getData();
      Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
   }
```